# What is the right unique id for a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use the FB graph API, I can access what appears to be the same object through different urls:

http://graph.facebook.com/170852259598827_10152051661624075&access_token=XXX

http://graph.facebook.com/10152051661624075&access_token=XXX

What is the different between the two ? What is the proper url I should use to manipulate this object ?

Answer (score 0):

Both urls are unique, you can use either of them.

In the first case, the ID is of format: **UserID/PageID_PostID**

and in second case, the ID is **PostID**

You can see in your case, 10152051661624075 which is the PostID is common in both the urls.

Comment: Yes, both urls are unique but the content returned appears to be slightly different and the fields available through the graph explorer are different. So, what is the conceptual difference for the FB servers between these two urls ?

Comment: I'm not sure why are you really interested in that, but you can always use the post_id; the first format could only be used to know who has shared this post and no other difference is there I guess. Conceptually, there's no such difference and when you try to access : https://www.facebook.com/<ID>; both urls will be redirect to the same url: https://www.facebook.com/<UserID>/posts/<PostID>